# How to make post request with JSON using Alamofire and Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift3, alamofire

This is my json that i want to use in params.

```
"Title":"You have a new gift from DevPro1034",
"StartDate":"2017-07-27T00:00:00",
"EndDate":"2017-07-29T00:00:00",
"ProviderId":"f6b80d00-410f-46c0-9087-167ecf853441”
"FeatureDetails":[
   {

      "CategoryId":21,    
      "ProviderFeatureDetailId":10803,
      "CustomServices":[
         {
            "ProviderCustomFeatureDetailId":13284,
            "InsiderPrice":8.0
         }
      ],
      "SortOrder":null,
      "CategorySortOrder":null
   },
   {
      "CategoryId":21,
      "ProviderFeatureDetailId":10803,
      "CustomServices":[
         {
            "ProviderCustomFeatureDetailId":13285,
            "InsiderPrice":15.0
         }
      ],
      "SortOrder":null,
      "CategorySortOrder":null
   }
],
"OldFavoriteOfferId":0,
"CurrentDate":"2017-07-26T00:00:00",
"InsiderOfferSlots":[
   {
      "ProviderAppointmentsId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "AppointmentDate":"2017-07-27T00:00:00",
      "StartTime":"2017-07-27T08:00:00",
      "EndTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "ProviderUserId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
   },
   {
      "ProviderAppointmentsId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "AppointmentDate":"2017-07-27T00:00:00",
      "StartTime":"2017-07-27T08:00:00",
      "EndTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "ProviderUserId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
   }


],
"CampaignDetails":{
   "CampaignId":0,
   "ProviderId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
   "CampaignMessage":"Hi [First_Name],\nThis is DevPro1034. We have a few last minute offers. See availability.\n\nCampaignLink\n\nReply STOP to opt out",
   "ScheduleDate":"2017-07-27T00:00:00",
   "IsSMS":true,
   "IsEmail":true,
   "IsNotification":true
},

}
```

This is my code that i am using for POST request.

```
var featureDetailArray = [[String:AnyObject]]()

    for campaign in camUser.getAllCustomServices{

        if campaign.insiderPrice != 0 {

            let customeServices = [["ProviderCustomFeatureDetailId" :campaign.providerCustomFeatureDetailId, "InsiderPrice": campaign.insiderPrice]]

            let parameter = ["CategoryId" :campaign.categoryId,
                             "ProviderFeatureDetailId": campaign.providerFeatureDetailId,
                             "CustomServices": customeServices
                ] as [String : Any]
            featureDetailArray.append(parameter as [String : AnyObject])
        }
    }

    // InsiderSlots

    var appointmentArray = [[String:AnyObject]]()


    for appintmentArray1 in camUser.startTimeDay1{

        let parameter = ["StartTime" :appintmentArray1,
                         "AppointmentDate": camUser.appointmentDate1,
                         "ProviderUserId": AuthService.instance.userId
            ] as [String : Any]
        appointmentArray.append(parameter as [String : AnyObject])
    }

    for appintmentArray2 in camUser.startTimeDay2{

        let parameter = ["StartTime" :appintmentArray2,
                         "AppointmentDate": camUser.appointmentDate2,
                         "ProviderUserId": AuthService.instance.userId
            ] as [String : Any]
        appointmentArray.append(parameter as [String : AnyObject])
    }

    for appintmentArray3 in camUser.startTimeDay3{

        let parameter = ["StartTime" :appintmentArray3,
                         "AppointmentDate": camUser.appointmentDate3,
                         "ProviderUserId": AuthService.instance.userId
            ] as [String : Any]
        appointmentArray.append(parameter as [String : AnyObject])
    }


    let campaignDetail = ["ProviderId": AuthService.instance.userId, "ScheduleDate":camUser.startDate,"CampaignMessage" : "Hi we are creating campaign", "IsSMS":camUser.isText, "IsEmail":camUser.isEmail, "IsNotification": camUser.isNotification] as [String : Any]



    let param : [String:Any] = [
        "Title": "You have a new gift from DevPro1034",
        "StartDate": camUser.startDate,
        "EndDate" : camUser.endDate,
        "ProviderId": AuthService.instance.userId,
        "FeatureDetails": featureDetailArray,
        "CurrentDate" : camUser.startDate,
        "InsiderOfferSlots" : appointmentArray,
        "CampaignDetails": campaignDetail
    ]

    let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: [])
    print(jsonData)
    let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableContainers)
    print(json)


    Alamofire.request(CREATE_CAMPAIGN, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding:JSONEncoding.default, headers: HEADER).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(param)
        if response.result.error == nil {
            NVActivityIndicatorPresenter.sharedInstance.stopAnimating()
             print(param)
             print(response)
             print(response.data ?? "")
            print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request!))")
            let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
            let message = json["Message"].stringValue

            print(message)
            print(json)
            completion(json)
        }else{
            //completion(false)
            debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
        }


    }


}
```

i have seen a lot of rated  answers but none of them was fixing my issue.

[Alamofire: Send JSON with Array of Dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204198/alamofire-send-json-with-array-of-dictionaries)

initially i got idea from this link, actually I want to send an array of dictionary and inside it have an other array of dictionary that is why i am so confused how to handle such kind of massy request for sending data to server side please help.

Comment: So what is your actual issue? Do you receive an error in the response? If so, what is the error? Or do you get a runtime error? Please be specific.

Comment: You also forgot to include the declaration of the variable `HEADER`