# Alamofire send Array of Dictionary to request

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a Array of Dictionary like so:

```
var jsonArrayOfDictionaries = [[AnyHashable: Any]]()

        for i in 0..<cellHolder.count {

            var jsonDict = [AnyHashable: Any]()

            jsonDict["scheduleTaskID"] = cellHolder[i].scheduleTaskID

            jsonDict["task"] = cellHolder[i].task

            jsonDict["scheduledDate"] = cellHolder[i].scheduledDate

            jsonDict["actualDate"] = cellHolder[i].actualDate

            jsonDict["finishedDate"] = cellHolder[i].finishedDate

            jsonDict["selected"] = (cellHolder[i].selected) ? 1 : 0

            jsonDict["completedBy"] = appDelegate.username

            jsonDict["sortOrder"] = cellHolder[i].sortOrder

            jsonArrayOfDictionaries.append(jsonDict)

            jsonDict = [AnyHashable: Any]()

        }
```

And I am trying to send that array to my Alamofire request call:

```
let credential = URLCredential(user: user!, password: password!, persistence: .forSession)

        let headers = ["Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "Content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"]

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: [:], headers: headers).authenticate(usingCredential: credential).responseJSON
```

But how do I send it as a parameter? or httpBody?

Comment: May help https://stackoverflow.com/a/42981893/5820010

Comment: just add a key `Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: ["list": jsonArrayOfDictionaries], headers: headers).authenticate(usingCredential: credential).responseJSON`

Comment: @Jaylon that did not work

Comment: @Sh_Khan what is bodyDictionary() ? I get an error: Value of type '[AnyHashable : Any]' has no member 'bodyDictionary'

Comment: what do you want tag of these data?